# Why is a value a vector?

Tags: r

This stomped me just now. I was testing whether something was a value, a vector or a list and this didn't make sense to me:

```
v <- 2
is.vector(v)
[1] TRUE
```

How is `v` a vector? How would I test if the value is just a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `TRUE` because `2` is numeric. Try changing the mode of `v`.
See `class(v)`

Reason: From `?is.vector`.

> is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise.
>   Also:
>   For is.vector, TRUE or FALSE. is.vector(x, mode = "numeric") can be true for vectors of types "integer" or "double" whereas is.vector(x, mode = "double") can only be true for those of type "double".

Further: We can define a numeric normally with `as.numeric`, note however that:

> The default method for is.numeric returns TRUE if its argument is of mode "numeric" (type "double" or type "integer") and not a factor, and FALSE otherwise. That is, is.integer(x) || is.double(x), or (mode(x) == "numeric") && !is.factor(x).

Therefore a numeric is really a vector of mode numeric.
The question then is what defines a vector.

Comment: How would I test if v is just a number?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no such thing as "just a number" in R, just a numeric vector of length 1

Comment: ah, ok. So everything is a vector by default except when it is declared to be a list,etc.?

Comment: Added. Can't upvote comments, my daily limit's up.

Comment: @Denis - A list is a vector too